# CakePHP PHPUnit Testing

Tags: cakephp, phpunit

I wrote the `testAdd()` method and try to debug the `$this->Article->getInsertID();` which currently returns `null` while `debug($articles)` correctly shows the newly inserted data.

```
public function testAdd() {
    $data = array(
        'Article' => array(
            'title' => 'Fourth Title',
            'content' => 'Fourth Title Body',
            'published' => '1',
            'created' => '2015-05-18 10:40:34',
            'updated' => '2015-05019 10:23:34'
        )
    );
    $this->_testAction('/articles/add', array('method' => 'post', 'data' => $data));
    $articles = $this->Article->find('first', array('order' => array('id DESC')));
    debug($articles);
    debug($this->Article->getInsertID);
    // return null. 

}
```

Why does `$this->Article->getInsertID()` return `null`?

Comment: You've written `$this->Article->getInsertID` in your example code, should it not read `$this->Article->getInsertID()`?

Comment: I wrote `$this->assertEqual(4, $this->Article->getInsertID)` and it shows the `Failed asserting that 4 matches expected null' errors.

Comment: It is a method not an attribute! http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/additional-methods-and-properties.html#model-getinsertid

Comment: Ya, It inserts a row with posted data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getInsertID` is a method not an attribute so you should use `$this->Article->getInsertID()` not `$this->Article->getInsertID`. However, rather than asserting the primary key value (which isn't an especially reliable test) assert that the data you've just inserted has saved to the database.

For example assert that the article `title` has saved:-

```
public function testAdd() {
    $data = array(
        'Article' => array(
            'title' => 'Fourth Title',
            'content' => 'Fourth Title Body',
            'published' => '1',
            'created' => '2015-05-18 10:40:34',
            'updated' => '2015-05019 10:23:34'
        )
    );
    $this->_testAction('/articles/add', array('method' => 'post', 'data' => $data));
    $result = $this->Article->find('first', array('order' => array('id DESC')));
    $this->assertEqual($data['Article']['title'], $result['Article']['title']);
}
```

Tests should be written so that you are 100% sure of what the result should be. The primary key is dependent on the current status of the database so may not necessarily be what you expect at the time of running the test.